# Math.floor(Math.random()) not displaying random numbers after first use

Tags: javascript, math, random, floor

I'm programming this really simple game, and want the damage done by each player random each hit. For some reason, the first hit has a random value, but then the next following values are exactly the same. It is almost like the `Math.floor(Math.random())` function runs once, then stops and uses the value it was given the first time.

Here's the code:

```
this.attackpoints=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+5);

this.attack=function(opponent) {

    opponent.hitpoints-=this.attackpoints;
    console.log(this.name + " has " + this.hitpoints + " hitpoints and " + this.energy + " energy.");
    console.log(this.name + " just hit " + opponent.name + ".");

}
```

Comment: *" It is almost like the `Math.floor(Math.random())` function runs once, then stops and uses the value it was given the first time."* Bingo. It only runs when you call it. How could it possibly know that you *don't* want to hold onto the original random value? Every time you need a random number, you need to generate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.attackpoints=function(){ return Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+5); };

this.attack=function(opponent) {

    opponent.hitpoints-=this.attackpoints();
    console.log(this.name + " has " + this.hitpoints + " hitpoints and " + this.energy + " energy.");
    console.log(this.name + " just hit " + opponent.name + ".");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only running `Math.random` once, when you initialize the value of `this.attackpoints`.

You could do this instead:

```
this.getAttackPoints = function() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+5);
}

this.attack=function(opponent) {
    opponent.hitpoints-=this.getAttackPoints();
    console.log(this.name + " has " + this.hitpoints + " hitpoints and " + this.energy + " energy.");
    console.log(this.name + " just hit " + opponent.name + ".");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function -

```
this.attackpoints= function () {
  return Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+5);
};
```

Then get a new random value by invoking your function -

```
opponent.hitpoints-=this.attackpoints();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfourtunately you didn't post the code where we could see, where your code above is called, but my guess is that you only call

```
this.attackpoints=Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+5);
```

once and afterwards you only use the attackpoints variable which stays the same all the time.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you always call the attackpoints variable of your object. Instead you should call a method that calculates the attackpoints again, and doesn't take the one from the variable.